# Anyone know if this daily report discontinue to publish? Goldman Sachs - "Global Index Volatility and Correlation Monitor"

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, data, market-data

I used to receive this daily report in my workplace from Goldman Sachs mailing list but the mailing list discontinued in May 2019 without any notice.

The report is an pdf attachment which send from "eq-sales-strats-ldn-rpts@gs.com". This email cannot be reached now.

Anyone here receive this report and know whether it is still publishing? 
Is there any contact point in Goldman Sachs so I can directly ask about it?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Very interesting question and if anyone has alternative newsletters would be great to get to know them

Comment: Is it something that should count as market research and therefore be paid for under mifid ii?

Comment: Hi will, thanks for the reply. I think my team is willing to pay however we just don't know how and where to subscribe this again. Anyone know which team of Goldman Sachs is preparing this report? eq-sales-strats-ldn-rpts stand for something like equity sales team?

Comment: You were referring to this, correct? https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2zohLDmfzuEJ:https://www.goldmansachs.com/what-we-do/global-markets/products-and-business-groups/products/index-methodologies-docs/gs-voyager-methodology.pdf+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us